# nonzero bounded linear operator is not bounded on $X$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed vector spaces. 
    A function $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is said to be **bounded** on $X$ if there exists a $M>0$ such that $\| f(x) \| \leq M$ for all $x \in X.$
    Show that a nonzero bounded linear operator $T:X \rightarrow Y$ is not bounded on $X.$

My attempt: I prove by contraposition.

Suppose that $T$ is bounded on $X.$ So there exists $M^{\prime}>0$ such that for all $x \in X,$ we have $\| T(x) \| \leq M^{\prime}.$

I need to prove that for all $M>0,$ there exists $x \in X$ such that $\| x \| \leq 1$ but $\| T(x) \| > M.$

Let $M>0$ be given. If $M>M^{\prime},$ then there does not exist $x \in X$ such that $\| T(x) \| >M$ as $M^{\prime}$ is an upper bounded for $\| T(x) \|$.

I do not know whether I am in the right track or not. It seems to me that question is wrong.

Comment: Simply use the homogenity of the norm. Since $T$ is non zero there exists $x\in X$ such that $T(x) = r \ne 0$. Thus $T(\lambda x) = \lambda r$

Comment: nonzero bounded linear operator is not bounded !!! 
Your question is wrong. The right one is that any nonzero linear operator is unbounded.

Comment: How is possible for a map be bounded and unbounded at same time?!

Comment: @nonlinearthought: Let $T(x) = x.$ It is a nonzero linear bounded operator, but not bounded on $X.$ Bounded operator just need to be bounded on $B_X.$

Comment: @Idonknow  I posted an answer here for corrected version of you question. Because I thought, it is a typos...  but after your comment under my answer, I understood it is a typos,  actually you have a wrong idea in your mind

Comment: https://books.google.com.sg/books?id=KSXUBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA1&lpg=PA1&dq=an+introductory+course+in+functional+analysis&source=bl&ots=kK1yHPgKv4&sig=ugubtOI--X-jDDtde1WrVVfi6Ng&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjTxpyI6p7UAhVBsI8KHfBVBAEQ6AEIQTAG#v=onepage&q=an%20introductory%20course%20in%20functional%20analysis&f=false

Comment: The question is taken from the book above, page $8$, exercise $1.4$

Comment: I took  the word "bounded"  as you defined, but first $bounded$ i.e, bounded operators refers to be  bounded on $B$. That made confusion. 

Moreover, As I said you don't need the assumption of being bounded operator.  Any nonzero operator is unbounded

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: take $x \in X$ such that $T(x) \neq 0$, Now Note that $T(\lambda x) =\lambda T(x)$  for all $\lambda \in R,  $.

BTW you are not in right track. when you say proof by contraposition,you must show that :  $T$ is bounded implies $T=0.$

However I suggest you prove it directly, i.e., show that if $T\neq 0$ implies $T$ is unbounded.

Comment: Direct proof: Let $M>0$ be given. Choose $x \in X$ such that $T(x) \neq 0.$ By assumption, we have $\| T(x) \| \leq M^{\prime} \cdot \| x \|.$ However, I want to get $\| T(x) \| > M.$ Can give more hint? Thanks.

Comment: $$\lim_{\lambda \rightarrow \infty} \|T(\lambda x)\|= \infty$$

Answer (score 1):

You can also use contraposition. You have to show:
if $T$ is bounded on $X$, then $T$ is not a non-zero, bounded, linear operator. Or, to put it in other words,
you have to check that

- $T$ is zero, or
- $T$ is not bounded on $B_X$ or
- $T$ is not linear.

Let us start with $\|T(x)\| \le M'$. If $T$ is not linear, we are done. Hence, suppose that $T$ is linear. Now, let $x \in X$ be arbitrary. Thus, $\lambda \, \|T x \| = \| T(\lambda \, x)\| \le M'$ holds for all $\lambda > 0$. Thus, $T x = 0$, i.e., $T = 0$.

Note that you cannot show that $T$ is not bounded on $B_X$ (since that is trivially satisfied). Indeed, one has the stronger statement: A non-zero, linear operator is not bounded on $X$.